# Pulseaudio not working right at login

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

So, I've been troubleshooting this since my sound card stopped working after a reboot a couple of days ago. I've made a lot of progress, but there's one last little thing I'm stuck on.

Right now, when I log in to the system, the audio output defaults to my television (tertiary monitor on the system), and my sound card is not listed as an available device.

However, when I run `pulseaudio -k`, it re-initializes and loads the sound card, which I can then select as the audio output device, and it works fine.

So, it seems like something is loading out of order, or perhaps too slowly, or something isn't waiting long enough when pulse audio originally initializes.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get pulesaudio to load correctly on my initial log in, so I don't need to pull up a terminal, kill it, and re-select my device every time I log in?

TIA!

Comment: I have also had this issue upon installtion of Ubuntu 20.04 onto an Acer Chromebook CB3-111 (Acer Chromebook 11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is fixed in a newer build. After updating my system with the `groovy proposed` source, it is loading correctly on startup.

I still had to set my default device on startup manually by editing `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and adding the set-default-sink option. E.g. `set-default-sink 0`

It's better to use the name of the sink rather than the index, to avoid any possible problems in the future with the indexes changing. You can find the name of the sink with `pacmd list-sinks`

Comment: Okay, so after further investigation, it looks like KDE simply calls pavucontrol, and the bug is there. https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/950 I filed a bug with KDE, and gave them two fixes/workarounds, but they didn't implement either one of them. :(